# Inserting index in variable name in Python

Tags: python

Does anyone know how I can insert index in variable name? Below, instead of `self.rpt1.IsBridge` , I want `1` in ‘`rpt1`’ coming from index in for loop, so that it will be `rpt1`, `rpt2`, `rpt3` and `rpt4`. There are all variables names not an array like rpt[n]

```
for i in range(1, 5):                
    Log.Print("(Summary) Rpt IsUp = %X"%self.rpt1.IsUp)
```

Answer (score 4):

Rather than a series of related variables, use a list.

```
self.rpts = [ ... ]
```

Then

```
for rpt in self.rpts:
    Log.Print("(Summary) Rpt IsUp = %X"%(rpt.IsUp))
```

Do not encode data in your variable names.

(This is no different in C, where you would prefer to use an array of pointers rather than a fixed set of pointers.)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a super standard thing, but you can do the following:

```
for i in range(1,5):
  Log.Print("(Summary) Rpt IsUp = %X" % getattr(self, 'rpt%s' % i).IsUp)
```

This uses [getattr](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) which looks up an attribute on the object in the first argument.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval):

```
for i in range(1, 5):                
    Log.Print("(Summary) Rpt IsUp = %X" % eval("self.rpt%d.IsUp"%i))
```

(It is a bad idea compared to using an array. Only if you don't have the choice, which rarely - never? - happens).